# Error pushing simple rails project to heroku, push rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku

I am following a tutorial at https://www.railstutorial.org/book. We make a very simple "hello world" application then at the end of the first chapter we push it to heroku. The app runs fine locally but I get a bunch of errors when trying to push it to heroku.
There is a warning about improperly formatted binstubs, errors about not being able to detect rake tasks, failed compilation, and a warning about the same version of code already being built. This is pretty much my first rails project and the first time deploying heroku so a lot of these errors make absolutely zero sense to me and i'm not sure what is breaking it.

````
> root@localhost:~/environment/hello_app# git push heroku main
> Enumerating objects: 146, done. Counting objects: 100% (146/146),
> done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects:
> 100% (127/127), done. Writing objects: 100% (146/146), 110.94 KiB |
> 1.98 MiB/s, done. Total 146 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source: remote: 
> remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack remote:  !     Warning:
> Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app.
> The first buildpack in the list below will be used. remote:
>           Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js remote:           See
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
> remote: -----> Ruby app detected remote: -----> Installing bundler
> 1.17.3 remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails remote:  remote:
> ###### WARNING: remote:  remote:        Improperly formatted binstubs detected in your project remote:         remote:        The following
> file(s) have appear to contain a problematic "shebang" line remote:   
> remote:          - bin/bundle remote:         remote:        For
> example bin/bundle has the shebang line: remote:         remote:      
> ``` remote:        #!/usr/bin/env ruby2.7 remote:        ``` remote:  
> remote:        It should be: remote:         remote:        ```
> remote:        #!/usr/bin/env ruby remote:        ``` remote:        
> remote:        A malformed shebang line may cause your program to
> crash. remote:         remote:        For more information about
> binstubs and "shebang" lines see: remote:         
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bad-ruby-binstub-shebang remote:
> remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6 remote: ----->
> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3 remote:        Running:
> BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle
> BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1
> BUNDLE_GLOBAL_PATH_APPENDS_RUBY_SCOPE=1 bundle install -j4 remote:    
> The dependency byebug (= 11.1.3) will be unused by any of the
> platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for
> aarch64-linux but the dependency is only for ruby, x86-mingw32,
> x64-mingw32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock
> --add-platform ruby x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32`. remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............ remote:       
> Fetching rake 13.0.3 remote:        Installing rake 13.0.3 remote:    
> Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8 remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.4.2
> remote:        Fetching minitest 5.14.3 remote:        Installing
> minitest 5.14.3 remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.4.2 remote:      
> Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8 remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
> remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4 remote:        Fetching erubi
> 1.10.0 remote:        Installing erubi 1.10.0 remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.5.0 remote:        Fetching racc 1.5.2 remote:       
> Installing mini_portile2 2.5.0 remote:        Installing racc 1.5.2
> with native extensions remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6 remote:    
> Installing crass 1.0.6 remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.3 remote:     
> Fetching nio4r 2.5.5 remote:        Installing rack 2.2.3 remote:     
> Installing nio4r 2.5.5 with native extensions remote:        Fetching
> websocket-extensions 0.1.5 remote:        Installing
> websocket-extensions 0.1.5 remote:        Fetching mimemagic 0.3.5
> remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.5 remote:        Fetching
> mini_mime 1.0.2 remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.0.2 remote:     
> Fetching msgpack 1.4.2 remote:        Installing msgpack 1.4.2 with
> native extensions remote:        Using bundler 2.1.2 remote:       
> Fetching ffi 1.14.2 remote:        Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native
> extensions remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0 remote:       
> Installing method_source 1.0.0 remote:        Fetching pg 0.20.0
> remote:        Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions remote:    
> Fetching thor 1.1.0 remote:        Installing thor 1.1.0 remote:      
> Fetching tilt 2.0.10 remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10 remote:    
> Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0 remote:        Installing
> turbolinks-source 5.2.0 remote:        Fetching i18n 1.8.9 remote:    
> Installing i18n 1.8.9 remote:        Fetching tzinfo 2.0.4 remote:    
> Installing tzinfo 2.0.4 remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
> remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0 remote:        Fetching
> rack-proxy 0.6.5 remote:        Installing rack-proxy 0.6.5 remote:   
> Fetching sprockets 4.0.2 remote:        Installing sprockets 4.0.2
> remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.3 remote:       
> Installing websocket-driver 0.7.3 with native extensions remote:      
> Fetching marcel 0.3.3 remote:        Installing marcel 0.3.3 remote:  
> Fetching mail 2.7.1 remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1 remote:      
> Fetching nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux) remote:        Installing
> nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux) remote:        Fetching puma 5.0.4
> remote:        Installing puma 5.0.4 with native extensions remote:   
> Fetching bootsnap 1.4.6 remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.4.6 with
> native extensions remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1 remote:    
> Installing turbolinks 5.2.1 remote:        Fetching activesupport
> 6.1.0 remote:        Installing activesupport 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching sassc 2.4.0 remote:        Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native
> extensions remote:        Fetching loofah 2.9.0 remote:       
> Installing loofah 2.9.0 remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing
> 2.0.3 remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3 remote:        Fetching globalid 0.4.2 remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.2
> remote:        Fetching activemodel 6.1.0 remote:        Installing
> activemodel 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.10.0 remote:     
> Installing jbuilder 2.10.0 remote:        Fetching
> rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0 remote:        Installing
> rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0 remote:        Fetching activejob 6.1.0
> remote:        Installing activejob 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching
> activerecord 6.1.0 remote:        Installing activerecord 6.1.0
> remote:        Fetching actionview 6.1.0 remote:        Installing
> actionview 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching actionpack 6.1.0 remote:     
> Installing actionpack 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching actioncable 6.1.0
> remote:        Fetching activestorage 6.1.0 remote:        Installing
> actioncable 6.1.0 remote:        Installing activestorage 6.1.0
> remote:        Fetching actionmailer 6.1.0 remote:        Installing
> actionmailer 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching railties 6.1.0 remote:     
> Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2 remote:        Installing railties
> 6.1.0 remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2 remote:        Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.0 remote:        Installing actionmailbox
> 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching actiontext 6.1.0 remote:        Installing actiontext 6.1.0 remote:        Fetching rails 6.1.0
> remote:        Fetching webpacker 4.2.2 remote:        Installing
> rails 6.1.0 remote:        Installing webpacker 4.2.2 remote:       
> Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2 remote:        Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
> remote:        Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0 remote:        Installing
> sass-rails 6.0.0 remote:        Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile
> dependencies, 57 gems now installed. remote:        Gems in the groups
> development and test were not installed. remote:        Bundled gems
> are installed into `./vendor/bundle` remote:        Bundle completed
> (254.77s) remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache. remote: ----->
> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64 remote: -----> Installing
> yarn-v1.22.4 remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks remote:  remote:  !
> remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks remote:  !     ensure you
> can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app remote:  !     and
> using the production group of your Gemfile. remote:  !    
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in
> `block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the
> sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `map!' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `materialize' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in
> `specs' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in
> `specs_for' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in
> `requested_specs' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in
> `block in definition_method' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in
> `setup' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in
> `setup' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in
> `<top (required)>' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' remote:  !     from /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/config/boot.rb:3:in
> `<top (required)>' remote:  !     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/bin/rake:3:in `require_relative' remote:  !    
> from /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/bin/rake:3:in `<main>' remote:  ! remote:
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in
> `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks
> (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError) remote:
> ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app remote:
> and using the production group of your Gemfile. remote:
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in
> `block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the
> sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) remote:    from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `map!' remote:    from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `materialize' remote:     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in
> `specs' remote:   from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in
> `specs_for' remote:   from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in
> `requested_specs' remote:     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in
> `block in definition_method' remote:  from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in
> `setup' remote:   from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in
> `setup' remote:   from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in
> `<top (required)>' remote:    from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' remote:     from
> /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' remote:     from /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top
> (required)>' remote:  from /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/bin/rake:3:in
> `require_relative' remote:    from /tmp/build_e4e63d0f/bin/rake:3:in
> `<main>' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1106:in
> `rake' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:78:in
> `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in
> `log' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:72:in
> `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in
> `run_assets_precompile_rake_task' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:116:in
> `block (2 levels) in compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1127:in
> `allow_git' remote:   from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in
> `block in compile' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:94:in
> `compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in
> `block in compile' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in
> `compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in
> `block in compile' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in
> `compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:35:in
> `block in compile' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:34:in
> `compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:20:in
> `block in compile' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:18:in
> `compile' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in
> `block (2 levels) in <main>' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in
> `log' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in
> `block in <main>' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in
> `block in trace' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument' remote:     from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime' remote:    from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument' remote:  from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in
> `trace' remote:   from
> /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in
> `<main>' remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
> remote:  remote:  !     Push failed remote:  ! remote:  ! ## Warning -
> The same version of this code has already been built:
> d3c258ea1dbc2f62936807e7363562fb7f66e9de remote:  ! remote:  ! We have
> detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version
> d3c258ea1dbc2f62936807e7363562fb7f66e9de remote:  ! at least twice.
> One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a
> different branch. remote:  ! remote:  ! If you are developing on a
> branch and deploying via git you must run: remote:  ! remote:  !    
> git push heroku <branchname>:main remote:  ! remote:  ! This article
> goes into details on the behavior: remote:  !  
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version remote: 
> remote: Verifying deploy... remote:  remote: !    Push rejected to
> floating-ocean-22006. remote:  To
> https://git.heroku.com/floating-ocean-22006.git  ! [remote rejected]
> main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some
> refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/floating-ocean-22006.git'
````

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error which mean you have multiple stacks setup for your application. So stack is actualy platform which is being used for different application. Now if you are using rails then you should specify your platform. You can check how many different stacks available using following command

```
heroku stack
```

And also check your buildpack, make sure it is heroku/ruby in case not I am setting in next commands.

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Now select your prefer stack by running following command, and also change buildpacks to heroku/ruby

```
heroku stack:set heroku-20
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

Above command will change your stack to heroku-20 for ruby, last night I used it to deploy rails 6 app.

```
git push heroku main
```

Still issue then you can try following command

```
heroku run bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

It should work if you change your stack, and still issues you can try changing stack to `heroku-18` and then do again `git push heroku main`

- `main` is branch you can change to `master` if you are using master as your primary branch.